# Formatting Enumerated columns

Tags: formatting

I am using writelatex.com to type my homework. The problem that I am having is that I can not format the two columns below as I want. what is happening is that all the information that comes after the enumerate portion is dropping to the end of the page Does anyone have any tips? Also I am not including the end of the enumerate because I would like to implement the method for this formatting to the next two parts I have.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\item $gcd(291,252)=\underline{3}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
291 & = 252 \cdot 1 + 39 \\
252 & = 39 \cdot 6 + 18 \\
18 & = 3 \cdot 6 + 0 \\
\end{aligned}

\end{equation*}

\columnbreak

\item $gcd(16261,85652)=\underline{161}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
85652 & = 16261 \cdot 5 + 4347 \\
16261 & = 4347 \cdot 3 + 3220 \\
4347 & = 3220 \cdot 1 + 1127 \\
3220 & = 1127 \cdot 2 + 966 \\
1127 & = 966 \cdot 1 + 161 \\
966 & = 161 \cdot 6 + 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have add the notes you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely `multicols*` is not to be used.

Also a display makes very difficult avoiding LaTeX trying to fill the left column. With `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$` the computations don't appear to hang from nowhere.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\item $\gcd(291,252)=\underline{3}$\\*[2ex]
$\begin{aligned}
291 & = 252 \cdot 1 + 39 \\
252 & = 39 \cdot 6 + 18 \\
18 & = 3 \cdot 6 + 0
\end{aligned}$

\columnbreak

\item $\gcd(16261,85652)=\underline{161}$\\*[2ex]
$\begin{aligned}
85652 & = 16261 \cdot 5 + 4347 \\
16261 & = 4347 \cdot 3 + 3220 \\
4347 & = 3220 \cdot 1 + 1127 \\
3220 & = 1127 \cdot 2 + 966 \\
1127 & = 966 \cdot 1 + 161 \\
966 & = 161 \cdot 6 + 0
\end{aligned}$
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for curiousity what does the \\*[2ex] do?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown The ``\\`` breaks the line, the `*` prohibits a page/column break, `[2ex]` adds a small vertical space.

Comment: Perfect. I will add this to my notes on using latex. I had another question how can I add more space between two columns?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown `\setlength{\columnsep}{18pt}` is the default; change it in the preamble to affect all `multicols` environments.

Comment: What if I just want to change one multicols

Comment: @UsernameUnknown In this case you can put the `\setlength` command between `\begin{enumerate}` and `\begin{multicols}`, because `\end{enumerate}` will reset the value.